# How to change SQLite time format datetime

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am trying to get the date from SQLite. I am getting timestamp in coredata, but I need to see the date. What is the command to get the timestamp converted into YYYY-MM-DD format? My query is:

```
SELECT ZDATE FROM ZWEATHER
```

Zdate is datetime.

Comment: What is the data type of `ZDATE`?

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for the `DATE()` function, [as seen in the SQLite manual](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

> SELECT date(ZDATE);

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to understand is that SQLite has no date type. It has no time type either.

It only offers some time functions. The [page](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) Piskvor links to is what you need. You enter the date and/or time in your database as a string following one of a few formats available:

- *YYYY-MM-DD*
- *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM*
- *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS*
- *YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS*
- *YYYY-MM-DD***T***HH:MM*
- *YYYY-MM-DD***T***HH:MM:SS*
- *YYYY-MM-DD***T***HH:MM:SS.SSS*
- *HH:MM*
- *HH:MM:SS*
- *HH:MM:SS.SSS*

Or as a floating point value representing the [Julian day number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day).